# Correct way to use ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView which I want to populate with a number of items depending on a received String. I currently have a Listview in which I "manually" add a few entries to try to get familiar with the concepts of **INotifyPropertyChanged** and **ObservableCollection**. What I want to do is have an Image that will change when the ListView item is tapped (for that specific tapped ListView item only). Currently, I have only been able to get it working by having the Image act as an ImageButton(Image Tapped Event). What would be the correct way to use these two properties together in a ListView?

I have only been working with Xamarin and C# for less than two weeks so I apologise if the answer or suggestion is very straightforward. Any help/advise or example will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My Relays class (with theINotifyPropertyChanged) is as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;


 namespace Socket.Models
 {


    public class Relays : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name =     
           "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new         
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    //public string ImageUrl { get; set; }    // The source of the 
                                             Image in the Listview 

    public int ID { get; set; }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name                      // The name of the item in 
                                               the ListView
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _ImageUrl;

    public string ImageUrl                      // The name of the 
                                         Image in the ListView
    {
        get
        {
            return _ImageUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ImageUrl != value)
            {
                _ImageUrl = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
       }

   }

 }
```

The RelayControl.xaml.cs class (with ObservableCollection) is as follows:

```
 using Socket.Models;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

 namespace Socket
 {
     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

     public partial class RelayControl : ContentPage
     {
         public Boolean RelayOn=false;                   // Used to                
                                                    check the State
         public string RelayName;                        // Used to 
                                               test the name change
         public string Images;                           // Used to 
                                                   change the Image
         public int RelayID;

         public RelayControl()
         {
             InitializeComponent ();
             Images= "ryno.jpg";
             RelayName = "Cool";
             loadSampleData();
             this.BindingContext = new Relays();         // Binding the 
                                                    Listview items

             var neg = lstView.BindingContext as Relays;

           //RelayOn = neg.isOn;                        // Assign the 
                            Binding OnProperty to the Boolean Variable
             RelayName = neg.Name;

             Images = neg.ImageUrl; 

             RelayID = neg.ID;
         }

         private void loadSampleData()
         {
        // Create sample data

             ObservableCollection<Relays> listRelays = new      
                               ObservableCollection<Relays>();

             listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name = "Relay " + 0, ImageUrl 
                                              = "ryno.jpg", ID = 0 });
             listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name = "Relay " + 1, ImageUrl 
                                    ="ryno.jpg", ID = 1 }); // num = i
             listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name = RelayName, ImageUrl = 
                                                    Images, ID = 2 });

             lstView.ItemsSource = listRelays;                 
         }

         public class MyListItemEventArgs : EventArgs
         {
             public Relays MyItem { get; set; }

             public MyListItemEventArgs(Relays item)
             {
                 this.MyItem = item;
             }
         }

         private void ImageCell_Tapped(object sender, 
                                      MyListItemEventArgs e)
         {
             var item = e.MyItem;

             if (item == null) return;

             if (item.ID == 2)
             {
                 if (RelayOn == true)
                 {
                     RelayName = "On";
                     Images = "on.jpg";
                     RelayOn = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     RelayName = "OFF";
                     Images = "off.jpg";
                     RelayOn = true;
                 }
             }

             loadSampleData();

         }
```

The RelayControl.xaml is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="Socket.RelayControl"
              Title="Relay Control Page">

     <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,10" Margin="2">
             <!--<SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar"                
             SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"> 
             </SearchBar>-->
             <ListView x:Name="lstView" SelectionMode="None" 
              RowHeight="50" >
                 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <ViewCell >
                             <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name,      
                                    Mode=OneWay}"
                                    x:Name="Received" 
                                    TextColor="#f35e20" 
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, 
                                 Mode=OneWay}" Aspect="AspectFit"  
                                 HeightRequest="50" 
                                 WidthRequest="110" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                                 VerticalOptions="Center">

                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                        Tapped="ImageCell_Tapped" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                                </Image>
                                <!--LabelText="{Binding Name}" 
                                TextColor="DarkGoldenrod" ImageSource=" 
                                {Binding ImageUrl}" 
                               Tapped="ImageCell_Tapped">-->

                                 </StackLayout>
                             </StackLayout>
                         </ViewCell>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>

         </StackLayout>
     </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of options for you. I would check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview

Comment: @snowCrabs, I will have a look at it; thanks.